# How to get all the folder name of android phone from internal storage and show it in the text-field?

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

What I want to do is to view all the folder name in the text-field from a specific location. For example, the given data path is-

```
android/data/
```

Here, inside data path we have some folders like `com.facebook.katana`, `com.android.browser`, `com.android.calendar` etc. Now what I want to do is to show all the folder names in a the text-field. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That path does not exist to begin with.

Comment: Can you explain why the path does not exist?

Comment: Well look for your self with a decent file explorer app on your device and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

The solution/hint is as follow.

- Use Kivy [FileChooserListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#usage-example)
- Add `path` and `filters`

### Snippet

```
<FileList>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            path: './'    # 'android/data'
            filters: ['com.*']
```

[FileChooser » path](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.path)

> ```
> path
> ```
>
> path is a StringProperty and defaults to the current working directory
>   as a unicode string. It specifies the path on the filesystem that this
>   controller should refer to.
>
> **Warning**
>
> If a unicode path is specified, all the files returned will be in
>   unicode, allowing the display of unicode files and paths. If a bytes
>   path is specified, only files and paths with ascii names will be
>   displayed properly: non-ascii filenames will be displayed and listed
>   with questions marks (?) instead of their unicode characters.

[FileChooser » filters](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.filters)

> ```
> filters
> ```
>
> filters specifies the filters to be applied to the files in the
>   directory. filters is a ListProperty and defaults to []. This is
>   equivalent to ‘*’ i.e. nothing is filtered.
>
> The filters are not reset when the path changes. You need to do that
>   yourself if desired.
>
> There are two kinds of filters: patterns and callbacks.
>
> ### Patterns
>
> e.g. [‘*.png’]. You can use the following patterns:
>
> Pattern   Meaning
>   * matches everything ?    matches any single character [seq]  matches any character in seq [!seq] matches any character not in seq
>
> ### Callbacks
>
> You can specify a function that will be called for each file. The
>   callback will be passed the folder and file name as the first and
>   second parameters respectively. It should return True to indicate a
>   match and False otherwise.

Comment: How can I use the filter in a text-field?